# How to use Mjml in angular application

Tags: angular, mjml

i am install the MJML into the my Angular6 application, i am write email template in MJML, now i need to convert this MJML email template into the HTML format on my build system ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use write .mjml files in one folder, after in your build system convert them into .html into your dist/ folder, use that .html files into your code.

if something face issue on build for work around directly copy that converted .html files into your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever need an additional source of information on MJML (as great as StackOverflow is!), you'll want to consider:

1. The Slack channel (for specific questions): https://slack.mjml.io/
2. Their web sites (for design, documentation, and code): https://mjml.io and https://github.com/mjmlio/mjml

Best of luck ...